# Key Error: None of [Int64Index([...]dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]

Tags: python, matplotlib

So here's my DataFrame:

```
    a        b      c
0   1971    2154    203020339
1   1972    2648    191489250
2   1973    2690    193377651
3   1974    2676    201291002
4   1975    3276    275380446
```

I tried to make a very simple plot with it:

```
df.plot(x = df['a'], y = df['b'])
```

But I keep getting a Key Error message:

```
None of [Int64Index([1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]
```

I tried to use convert column [a] to DateTime but I still got the same error message.

```
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format='%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the pandas plot, you already have a data frame, so the column name must be a name.

```
df.plot(x='a', y='b')
```

[image]